# receive types from a array of objects value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

i want to generate types out from a array of objects.

```js
const names = [
  {
    name: 'Bob'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane'
  },
  {
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike'
  },
]
```

the result should be look like this:

```js
type NameType = 'Bob' | 'Jane' | 'John' | 'Mike'
```

i saw a lot of references, for example this [typescript-types-from-arrays](https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/)

but these examples always use a array of strings as resource.
like:

```js
const array = ['one', 'two',...]
```

which works flawless.

but what i try to do is generating the types with a `array.map` like this:

```js
const allNames = names.map((item) => item.name) as const;

type NameType = typeof names[number];
```

but this leads into a:

```
A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to
enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.
```

here is a playable example of what i try to do:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jgzdkq?file=index.ts)

i want to use the function `getName()` with IntelliSense to know which names are available in the `names` array.
like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be still achieved using a combination of `as const` and [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

```
const names = [
  {
    name: 'Bob'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane'
  },
  {
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike'
  },
] as const

type NameType = typeof names[number]['name'];
// type NameType = "Bob" | "Jane" | "John" | "Mike"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtAUDGA3nvnEsgFwwDkAQiAEZXEC%20ANMUSaSpVQFLwwyJvjYdi%20BD2p8QACzAiYY-JxJSK1ALIBLANbCW7ALox4aUJCg4cUAJ4AHZDAByZACqPnme05AAzblQsMABXRHpkACdjLCoNKmMAbiA)